# Given a java.lang.reflect.Method object, is there an easy way to obtain a hierachry of the methods it overrides

Tags: java, reflection

Given a java.lang.reflect.Method object, is there an easy way to obtain a hierachry of the methods it overrides. For example:

```
class A {
    public void someMethod() { ... }
}

interface B {
    public void someMethod();
}

class C extends A {
    public void someMethod() { ... }
}

class D extends C implements B {
    public void someMethod() { ... }
}
```

Given the java.lang.reflect.Method object for D#someMethod, can I easily get the tree:

```
D#someMethod
 |
 +- C#someMethod
 |   |
 |   +- A#someMethod
 |
 +- B#someMethod
```

Am guessing there must be a simple way of doing this, perhaps an existing library?

Comment: You could go through the hierarchy with the `Class#getSuperClass()` method and check for each of the super classes whether they have that method or not.

Comment: Yup had considered that, was hoping there might be a nicer way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately did not find a useful library, so as per assylias comment simply used reflection to traverse the inheritance and build a tree (including superclasses and interfaces). I didn't build a method tree but rather a class tree which can subsequently be 'walked'.