# Get class in which method of object is implemented

Tags: java, reflection

I have an object `object` and I'm going to call it's method `toString`. How do I know in what exact class this method is implemented last?

For example if we have hierarchy:

```
class A /*extends Object */{                                                                                                              

}                                                                                                                      
class B extends A{                                                                                                              
    public String toString() {                                                                                         
        return "representation";                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                      
class C extends B{                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                      
class D extends C{                                                                                                              
}
```

and the object

```
Object object = new SomeClass(); //(A/B/C/D/Object)
```

then for `toString()` I should get `Object` for `Object` and `A` but `B` for `B`, `C` and `D`

Comment: Huh?  What is `someMethod()`?  Where is the hierarchy?  What does `toString()` have to do with anything?

Comment: You question is quite unclear to me.

Comment: Related (but without a good answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934675/given-a-java-lang-reflect-method-object-is-there-an-easy-way-to-obtain-a-hierac?rq=1

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, sorry, I've forgot to write extends that I mean to be here, fixed

Comment: Ok, that's kind of what I assumed ;)  So given `object`, you want to know (via reflection) whether `object.toString()` would call `B.toString()` or `Object.toString()`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Method.getDeclaringClass()` method:

```
...
private Class<?> definingClass(Class<?> clz, String method) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    Method m = clz.getMethod(method);
    return m.getDeclaringClass();
}

...

System.err.println(definingClass(A.class, "toString"));
System.err.println(definingClass(B.class, "toString"));
System.err.println(definingClass(C.class, "toString"));
System.err.println(definingClass(D.class, "toString"));

...
```

Result:

```
class java.lang.Object
class com.example.B
class com.example.B
class com.example.B
```

You need to extend the `definingClass()` method appropriately if you need to look up methods which have parameters.